# NotificationHub vs NotificationHubClient

Tags: azure, notifications, push-notification

Seems like these are two similar classes in different namespace. Not sure which one to use.

Here's what I got out of MSDN:

**NotificationHub** is in *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging* Namespace, appeared under windows store App API. So I can only use them in windows store apps?

**NotificationHubClient** is in *Microsoft.ServiceBus.Notifications* Namespace, under Windows Azure Service Bus. Use in any .Net applications?

Is this correct? Should I stick with  NotificationHubClient? is there any reason to use NotificationHub instead of NotificationHubClient?

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

'NotificationHub' is for windows store apps. Please refer to http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/
for sample.

'NotificationHubClient' is for .NET back-ends to communicate with notification hubs.

Hope this helps.